# Is there a view in SQL Server that lists just primary keys?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, system-views

I'm working with SQL Server and trying to do a little "reflection," if you will. I've found the system view `sys.identity_columns`, which contains all of the identity columns for all of my tables.

However, I need to be able to select information about primary keys that aren't identity columns. Is there a view that contains data about all primary keys and only primary keys? If not, how else can I get this data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for SQL Server 2005 and higher:

```
select OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(i.object_id), OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id), i.name
from sys.indexes i
where i.is_primary_key = 1
order by 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks.  Apparently I have to wait 9 minutes to accept your answer as correct, but I will.

Comment: "However, I need to be able to select information about primary keys that aren't identity columns." I think this query will not full fill above requirements

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name FROM sys.key_constraints WHERE type = 'PK';
SELECT name FROM sys.key_constraints WHERE type = 'UQ';
```

Answer (score 1):

i realize that the question has already been marked as answered, but it might also be helpful to some to show how to incorporate `sys.index_columns` (in addition to `sys.indexes`) to your query in order to tie the actual primary key index to the table's columns.  example:

```
select
    t.Name as tableName
    ,c.name as columnName
    ,case when pk.is_primary_key is not null then 1 else 0 end as isPrimaryKeyColumn
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
left join sys.index_columns pkCols 
    on t.object_id = pkCols.object_id 
    and c.column_id = pkCols.column_id
left join sys.indexes pk 
    on pkCols.object_id = pk.object_id 
    and pk.is_primary_key = 1
where 
    t.name = 'MyTable'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT KC.TABLE_NAME, KC.COLUMN_NAME, KC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KC
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(KC.CONSTRAINT_NAME), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 0
```